# After completing the 'main' quest, is there any sort of reward or recognition for your accomplishments?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I finished the main story. I got back to Tamriel, expected some kind of a ... reward. You know, for saving the world etc. But *nobody* I've spoken to seems to care at all about that. Am I doing something wrong or is the main storyline actually ... not that 'main'?

In Oblivion, after finishing the game, I got a title, equipment, everybody talked to me like to a hero, there was this big *Martin* Dragon in the Talos Plaza in IC, but nothing grandiose seems to be here this time :/

I don't mean this question as a request for opinions, I know that is not allowed at stackexchange, I just want to know if that's really it?

Comment: i was wondering the same thing, i searched the web wondering if i did the main storyline, because it just sort of ended after killing Alduin, it was like... is that it? but ya apparently thats how it ends and now you can finish the quest of either the imperial or stormcloaks and help the war. also if you go back and talk to the grey beards, they will ask you if you really killed him and blah blah blah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A guard in Whiterun said "Hail Dragonkin, hero of Skyrim" to me, which I thought was awful nice. And someone else thanked me for ending a great evil or something.

But yeah, overall it feels like people could be a little nicer, given that I prevented the world from ending...

Comment: Yeah, but the question asked if you did something to trigger that sequence, and if you did, what was it?

Comment: You're what? The 5th guy in a row to save the world form an ancient malignant evil? People get tired of that stuff.

Comment: You do finally get to make use of the Call Dragon and Call of Valor Shouts!